Error with MSAL4J in RJDBC with ActiveDirectoryMSI
I am trying to establish a connection in Mac via the company portal with R. I am basically trying to copy a connection that actually works with DBeaver, using RJDBC.
It returns this error:

Failed to load MSAL4J Java library for performing ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity authentication

I've been trying different things but I dont know how to manage it, I've tried to change the authentication type (which won't work in my server and even changed the JAVA versions to older ones but was not successfull.
As can be seen in the photo, this is the connection that is already working with Dbeaver in mac.

This is the reason why I decided to go and try to emulate it on R.
This is the code I am running on R at the moment and the error (I changed my server name with 'serverworkspace').
drv <- RJDBC::JDBC(driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", classPath ="~/Documents/Java/sqljdbc_12.6/enu/jars/mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar")

conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=serverworkspace-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net;;authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI;;encrypt=true")

And this would be the entire error:

conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=serverworkspace-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net;;authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI;;encrypt=true")
Error in dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=serverworkspace-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net;;authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI;;encrypt=true") :
Unable to connect JDBC to jdbc:sqlserver://;serverName=serverworkspace-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net;;authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI;;encrypt=true
JDBC ERROR: Failed to load MSAL4J Java library for performing ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity authentication.


you probably need to get com.microsoft.azure.msal4j lib and put it on the classpath. Probably easiest to get it in maven

Hi siggemannen, thanks for your tip. Unfortunately I know nothing about java, I'm basically trying to connect my mac into an Azure Synapse server and trying to emulate what it is working through Dbeaver... basically I don't exactly know how to get this library into the jar. I edited the post because I realized the classpath was not correct, it goes straight to Microsoft's provided jar file"~/Documents/Java/sqljdbc_12.6/enu/jars/mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre11.jar",  and I don't know how to insert the different files I got downloaded from maven following your suggestion. I would appreciate any help.

i'm not sure, either send multiple file pathes as array or vector (i don't know R at all), or send a string separated by ;
